# Find Unique Subsets problem different approach

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

I have tried this solution to find subsets of a set but instead of using int I used strings as just got the question from a friend and didn't knew that it required integer input but the solutions I checked online have more time complexity than my solution, also sorry if I calculated the time complexity wrong, is this solution viable if the integer input from the question is converted to string and then back again to int when it is to be returned.

**I claim time complexity to be O(2*N)+O((2*N)+2)=O(N),N=size of string**

Pseudocode:

Step0: Check for condition if size of string is!=1

Step1: Store empty set in Subsets vector

Step2: Till i is less than size of string push the single characters of string into Subsets vector

Step3: After that push j,j+1 elements of string into Subsets and increment i,j

Step4: If j==lastindex push first element of string+jth element of string into Subsets vector

Step5: Print the elements of Subsets vector

Step6: Push the string into Subsets vector

Step7: If size==1 then push empty space and string into Subsets vector

Step8: Print Subsets vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string n;
    cin>>n;
    int i=0,j=0;
    vector<string> Subsets;
    Subsets.push_back(" ");
    if(n.size()!=1)
    {
    while(i<=(n.size()*2)) //O(2*N)
    {
        if(i<n.size())
        {
            string temp;
            temp+=n[i];
            Subsets.push_back(temp);
            ++i;
        }
        else
        {
            string temp;
            temp+=n[j];
            temp+={','};
            temp+=n[j+1];
            Subsets.push_back(temp);
            ++i;
            ++j;
            if(j==n.size()-1)
            {
                string temp1;
                temp1+=n[0];
                temp1+={','};
                temp1+=n[j];
                Subsets.push_back(temp1);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    Subsets.push_back(n);
    cout<<"[";
    for(int i=0;i!=Subsets.size();++i) //O(2*n)+2
    {
        if(i==Subsets.size()-1)
        {
            cout<<"["<<Subsets[i]<<"]";
            break;
        }
        cout<<"["<<Subsets[i]<<"],";
    }
    cout<<"]";
    }
    else{
        Subsets.push_back(n);
        for(int i=0;i!=Subsets.size();++i)
        {
            if(i==Subsets.size()-1)
            {
                cout<<"["<<Subsets[i]<<"]";
                break;
            }
            cout<<"["<<Subsets[i]<<"],";
    }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What time complexity are you claiming this has? Can you add pseudocode to your question?

Comment: @Dave done, please check it out

Comment: Your program does not produce correct results, so its time complexity is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes I just noticed I didn't account for subsets having more than 2 pairs thanks for the answer